# recursive function as circular funciton

Tags: terminology

I recently learnt that a recursive function is also referred to as a circular function.

See, the recursive function cannot be a circular function because even if there is a call to function itself, it does not happen indefinitely. There is always a base case (or condition) from where the function is supposed to exit in one way or the other (either by displaying some message or returning some value).

So, is calling recursive function, a circular function not a misnomer ?

Comment: I've never heard the term "circular function" to mean anything other than "[trigonometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularFunctions.html)".  Do you have any examples of this term being used?

Comment: There can't be any "circularity" involved, as that would lead to an infinite loop not a computation of a function.

Comment: I just happened to encounter this word in context to recursive function and that was something not soothing to my eyes. That is why I asked this question.....

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it's a misnomer. Consensus from the comments seems to be that "circular function" is not a commonly used term for a recursive function. I think the person you saw using the term was using the wrong word, perhaps because of translation issues.